# CSS for WP Menu links

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, themes

I install wp on my localhost, Now i want to add class for menu links but i don't know where,
    code look like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); >
```

where i there need to add my css class for change fonts color,size,underline of menu links ?
Thanks.

Comment: You add it in the `styles.css` file

Comment: Read up http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu by what you've pasted you'll want to alter .menu-item

Comment: I add in styles.css but not work this always get from my general links css:

a:link {color:#ff7800;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#ff7800;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#ff7800; text-decoration:underline;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#ff7800;}  /* selected link */

but i want special for menu, how i can do this ?

Comment: are you adding this css you defined to the nav-menu class in your css file?

Comment: @Robert Lee no, u want to tell i need make new css class who have name ''nav-menu'' ?

Comment: If you look at your menu, is there a class defined to the menu items?

Comment: @RobertLee I try to add in css file, ''nav-menu'' but links not change again ?

Comment: you may have something that is conflicting.

Comment: @RobertLee maybe i need add ''menu_class'' ?

Comment: In your wp_nav_menu you have already defined menu_class as 'nav-menu'

Comment: @RobertLee yes and i try add this nav-menu in css and not work, can u please suggest me how i need add this nav-menu lik .nav-menu or #nav-menu ? maybe there i make error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to make your styles specific depending on what element they are inside. You can see what I mean in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4AbX/2/). Notice how all of the links are the colors you have asked for, but the links inside the ul with a nav-menu class are different colors. This is the kind of code you will need to add to `styles.css`. You can also change the class of the  output by WordPress in your PHP code like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'my-custom-class' ) ); >
```

If you're having a problem with your code getting overwritten, try adding it to the very very bottom. CSS interprets things at the bottom of your file as more important than things at the top.

Comment: If this worked for you, could you please accept my answer? Thanks to you too, I'm glad it helped :)